# Updating an image view through the use of a handler - how to correctly use a conditional statement?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am attempting to create a simple practice Morse code application. I would like an image view to change color based on a given Morse code sequence. I have attempted to do this using a handler which updates the image view in the UI thread.

The problem is that even though i can return a message i am unsure of how to use the returned information to change the color if the image view. I am not sure if i have done this correctly (this is all new to me) but i have created a bundle which is sent to the UI - it is this information that i need to use to determine which color the image view should be. I am wondering if anyone has any ideas/advice as the best way to go about this? I am on the brink of my knowledge here and have attempted to research this topic.

```
  //Handler which receives the message
  static Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

         Bundle bundle = msg.getData();

         String str1 = bundle.getString("dot");
         String str2 = bundle.getString("dash");

  //I think i need to use a conditional statement here

    }
 }; 


  //Logic done within the worker thread
 for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        if (cArray[i] == '.') {

            msg = new Message();

            bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("dot", "dot dot dot");

            msg.setData(bundle);

            Sos.myHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(offIntervalTime);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        } else if(cArray[i] == ' ')
        {
            try{

                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
        else {

            msg = new Message();

            bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("dash", "dash dash dash");

            msg.setData(bundle);

            Sos.myHandler.sendMessage(msg);

            try{

                Thread.sleep(dash);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
            try{

                Thread.sleep(offIntervalTime);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: use msg.what value to set/get and take actions based the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That worked perfectly - i had come across the what values using a switch statement in some examples but i being new to me i thought an if statement would work if applied correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my suggestion works for you, adding it as an answer.

use `msg.what` value to set/get and take actions based the same.

Comment: This worked as required. I just needed a push in the right direction - thank you.